# How do I submit a iMessage Stand Alone App?

Tags: ios, app-store-connect, imessage

And why does it keep asking me to provide iPhone and iPad screenshots (on top of the image previews for the iMessage).
It is quite confusing when I go to submit and I am unsure if I created a stand alone app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For submission in iTunes connect of a stand alone iMessage app you still need to submit the information and screenshots for a normal iPhone and iPad app as well. Apple requires this because the iMessage will be shown on iPhone and iPads.